# Automount DMG file on login

Tags: macos

I have a DMG file that I'd like automounted on login. How can I do this?

Comment: Works for me on Lion. System Preferences -> Users & Groups -> Login Items. "+" button to add a new login item, choose a dmg. Logged out then in, DMG mounted.

Answer (score 7):

create a bash script called mountMyDrive like this..

```
#!/bin/bash
hdiutil mount /Users/anydir/your.dmg
exit 0
```

then:

create a plist file called mount.my.drive.plist

```
<plist version="1.0">
   <dict>
     <key>Label</key>
     <string>mount.my.drive</string>
     <key>OnDemand</key>
      <false/>
      <key>Program</key>
       <string>Users/anydir/mountMyDrive</string>
   </dict>
</plist>
```

Put this plist file in /Library/LaunchAgents/

Voila...

Each time you log in your dmg will be mounted

I did this a year ago to share the IPhoto lib with my wife on the same Imac i have...
Work perfect